# Error TypeError - Make statement

Tags: javascript

In my var :

```
var myvar = myNav.tips[TrsId];
```

I have an error in my console :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

I have try to make a if Statement but that's not work. How can i do if it's undefined or '0', i do another thing.

In the Google Chrome Console, `TrsId` is highlighted (and the error in the console come from this)

Thanks

Comment: myNav doesn't have tips property

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear but what I understood is you want to handle `undefined`. 
You can achieve it by using following steps:

1 check whether myNav has tips property. Ie.

```
if (myNav.tips!= undefined) {
  // Your code
}
```

2 if it's undefined then you can throw the exception by writing code in try catch

Answer (score 0):

Not `TrsId` is the problem, but `tips` is undefined. Make sure `tips` exists. For example like this

```
var tip = null;
if (myNav.tips !== undefined) {
    tip = myNav.tips[trsId];
}
```